# angularjs and spring security redirecting to login on session timeout

Tags: angularjs, spring, session, spring-security

I am using spring security with angularjs, when my session times out i return an endpoint with JSON saying the session is invalid and using angularjs I try to redirect to my login page. The problem when I redirect to the login page is that the session is no longer timed out, and thus redirects to the index page.

**spring security**

```
<form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/index"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?loginFailed=true"/>
    <logout
            logout-success-url="/login"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    <session-management
            invalid-session-url="/invalid">
        <concurrency-control
                max-sessions="1"
                expired-url="/login"
                error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
        />
    </session-management>
```

**restful service**

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/invalid")
@ResponseBody
public String invalidateSession() {
    return "{\"invalidSession\":true}";
}
```

**angularjs**

```
if(result.data.hasOwnProperty("invalidSession") && result.data.invalidSession == true){
            $location.path("/login");

        }
```

I discovered this also causes an issue with spring security roles. While spring should redirect users with the configuration

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/index">
```

It does not redirect users, rather it returns the HTML page.

Could all of this be causes by angularjs routes, and that I inject all pages into a single html page?

Comment: need to understand few things : 1. is invalidateSession() getting called 2.if 1 is happening then is $location.path("/login"); getting called

Comment: @Mudassar yes invalidateSession gets called and returned, and `$location.path("/login");` gets called as well. I tried to explain in question that when i call `$location.path("/login");` the login page redirects to the index page.

Comment: what leads to calling /invalid, I mean do you manually call /invalid or there's code due to which /invalid gets initiated

Comment: @Mudassar , /invalid is triggered from spring security in session management `invalid-session-url="/invalid"`

Comment: Ya I figured that but my question was how do you know for sure if spring security is calling it

Comment: Don't get me wrong but the reason I'm asking this is because it seems that the session never times out and still active hence the directed flow to index page happens

Comment: @Mudassar it is for sure spring security, if I change /invalid to another endpoint that new endpoint will return.